# Why is Eclipse launching my applications with default-encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

When I run an application from Eclipse, it uses for some reason UTF-8 as the encoding. However, when I create a jar and run it outside of eclipse, I get my machine's encoding (Cp-1252.) Also, when running TestNG from eclipse, the encoding is Cp-1252.

Why is the "inherited" UTF-8? I can't see any setting that may control it (and it is NOT Preference/General/Workspace/Text file encoding. That one is about the encoding of source files)

[image]

Comment: Is it a maven project?

Comment: Yes, _default - inherited_ means here, set `-Dfile.encoding` to the project source/test file encoding (_Project > Properties: Resource: Text file encoding_ which itself can inherit from _Preferences: General > Workspace: Text file encoding_). Change this value and you will see. Why doesn't it make sense to you (please be aware, that for `.class` files no encoding can be set or is required)?

Comment: Because it is the encoding of the source files, not the encoding of my input

Comment: Also, changing Resource:Text file encoding didn't fix it